# How do I get my "else if" statement to register a number or special character?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get an input of either an uppercase letter, lowercase letter or a number and outputting whether or not the input is one of the three or a special character. When I enter either an uppercase or lower case letter, the program is able to identify the difference, however when I input a number or a special character it always returns as an uppercase letter.

```js
let upperLowerNumber = prompt("Please enter either an uppercase letter, a lower case letter or a number:");

if(upperLowerNumber === upperLowerNumber.toUpperCase()){
    console.log(`${upperLowerNumber} is an uppercase letter.`);
}
else if(upperLowerNumber === upperLowerNumber.toLowerCase()){
    console.log(`${upperLowerNumber} is a lowercase letter.`);
}
else if(upperLowerNumber == Number.isInteger(upperLowerNumber)){
    console.log(`${upperLowerNumber} is a number.`);
}
else  {
    console.log(`${upperLowerNumber} is not a letter or number.`);
}
```

Comment: Consider that numbers are the same in upper and lower case…

Comment: Number being the same in both upper and lower case is part of the problem. The other part of the problem is that `Number.isInteger` will return false if you call it with a string, even if that string happens to only consist of numbers. That is: `Number.isInteger(5)` will return `true`, but `Number.isInteger("5")` will return `false`.

Comment: If only using with the Latin alphabet, consider using `if (/^[A-Z]$/.test(upperLowerNumber))`.  This also gives you a length test (requiring length is 1) "for free"